# When is entity replacement necessary for relation extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

In this [tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/09/13/training-a-classifier-for-relation-extraction-from-medical-literature/#Reuse) for "Training a Machine Learning Classifier for Relation Extraction from Medical Literature" the author does Entity replacement because that "we don’t want the model to learn according to a specific entity name, but we want it to learn according to the structure of the text".

Is this generally true or does it depend on the dataset or the used models?

Answer (score 0):

Entity replacement, much like other text transformation techniques including stemming and lemmatization, is usually a part of the relationship extraction process because it increases the number of observation per feature. That increase in ratio might help your problem, depending on the size of the dataset, quality of features, type of feature extraction, and complexity of the model.

A good rule of thumb is to define your objective and subsequently your **acceptable representation** based on your understanding of the dataset. For instance, the given tutorial sets out to understand the relationship between miRNA and genes. The author is *okay* with grouping miRNA-335, miRNA-342, miRNA-100 and others, under the same entity name.

In scenarios, where you don't have domain understanding of the corpora, you can start out without entity replacement, inspect the result and understand the model's bias-variance tradeoff. Then, if required, try entity replacement after experimenting with some clustering techniques.